# Flat csv data to Json

Tags: json, serialization

I am trying to process a Json data in Java. I have the data in below format (it is nested data structure with arrays etc.)

```
person.name,person.friend[0],person.friend[1],person.address.city,person.address.country
1,x,y,kolkata,india
2,a,b,london,uk
```

The first line is header denoting the nested object hierarchy. I want a json in below format,

```
{
"data" : [
{
  "name" : "1",
  "friend" : ["x","y"],
  "address" : { "city" : "kolkata", "country" : "india" }
},
{
  "name" : "2",
  "friend" : ["a","b"],
  "address" : { "city" : "london", "country" : "uk" }
} ]
}
```

**The object structure is dynamic and I dont know the columns or header in advance, i.e. I can not use any predefined POJO to get populated with the data. In this example, it "Person" object but it may be any object structure.**

I have gone through Jackson or Gson API, but none seems to fulfill this requirement. Is there any API that can help? or any other wayout?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it in 2 steps.

First, you have to parse your CSV. I recommend [superCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_reading.html). Parsing CSV may be fancy sometimes, so I really recommend you to use a library for that.

Second, you can serialize into JSON. Then you can use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), [flexjson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/), whatever.

Comment: Thanks @Leo for the reply!! But I forgot to mention that, the object structure is dynamic, I dont know the header in advance...in that case I guess, SuperCSV will not work..ryt?

Comment: it does not need the header, but of course, the code can't simply guess how to interpret the data. You have to code it yourself somehow.

Answer (score 0):

After a long Google...I found that the only option is to represent a collection based object structure in flat file is repeated rows,

```
person.name,person.friends,person.address.city,person.address.country
1,x,kolkata,india
1,y,kolkata,india
2,a,london,uk
2,b,london,uk
```

where the non-array elements repeats. We need to form a json from this, then need to filter or club the same object by its ID (here person.name)